Expired permesso with valid student d type visa
I am an Erasmus student in Italy. I have a student d type visa valid till 9th January 2025. However, the permesso issued to me was valid only till 30th November 2024. Infact, I received the permesso on 2nd December, when it was already expired. I cannot apply for renewal as my program is not extendable. Is it okay if I stay in Italy till my d type visa is valid ? I have booked my flights back to India for 6th January, 2025 before the visa expiry. Has anyone been through a similar situation. Please guide me, I am really confused.
